# ¿Cómo almacenar objetos en un vba ListBox y recuperarlos cuando hacemos clic en ellos?

Tags: vba

Hice un método que toma una matriz global de objetos arrayOReservists, que representa a las personas, y muestra sus objetos en un ListBox.

```
        ' Rellenamos los resultados de ListBox con los nombres y apellidos del personal
        ListBoxResults.AddItem (arrayOReservists(i).Surname & " " & arrayOReservists(i).Name)
        ' redimensionamos la tabla
        i = i + 1
```

Otro método, `ListBoxResults_DblClick`, responde cuando hago doble clic en una de las líneas del ListBox. Muestra un UserForm al que me gustaría enviar el objeto en el que hice clic. Sin embargo, no sé cómo acceder a este objeto. Tengo la impresión de que los datos transmitidos a ListBox por AddItem se transforman en texto.

```
Private Sub ListBoxResults_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim newInstanceOfMe As Object

    ' Buscamos el nombre y apellido del reservista al que hicimos clic.
    For i = 0 To ListBoxResults.ListCount - 1
        If ListBoxResults.Selected(i) Then
            ReservistName = ListBoxResults.List(i)
        End If
    Next i

    ' Tenga en cuenta el caso en el que hace clic en los Resultados de TextBox mientras está vacío
    If False Then
        If ReservistName <> "" Then
            Set newInstanceOfMe = UserForms.Add(Me.Name)          
            newInstanceOfMe.Caption = ReservistName
            newInstanceOfMe.Show
            Unload newInstanceOfMe
            Set newInstanceOfMe = Nothing
        End If
    End If
    ' Pase el nombre, primer nombre a ReservistUserForm y en la Carga que filtra la lista de estos campos obteniendo el objeto oReservist.
    ' Una vez tengas la informacion de ese usuario lo siguiente sera mapear la informacion a los textBox correspondientes.
    ReservistFormUserForm.Caption = ReservistName
    ReservistFormUserForm.Show

End Sub
```

De hecho, cuando muestro `MsgBox (ListBoxResults.List (i))` Solo tengo el nombre y apellido y no el objeto.

Por lo tanto, cómo almacenar objetos en un vba ListBox y recuperarlos cuando hacemos clic en ellos. Esto me permitirá, por ejemplo, colocarlos en una variable global a la que tendré acceso en el UserForm.